# Infinity in the request urls

Tags: nginx, cloudflare, dig, fastly

Did anyone had problems with request URLs that finish with `Infinity`?

Happens that our server logs are receiving somehow, someway requests with this pattern. I don't know if is a pattern or any kind of computation that returns an overflow, or if is any CDN that is messing up with the paths.

Despite of this might be a silly question, maybe I can reach some insight about how to trace the cause of the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This will be hard to find. Some screenshots of the logs will also help..

Comment: All I've found about this sort of thing is React components getting into a loop and causing Infinity number of requests (which ties in with the Infinity global property in JS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity).

Comment: Also, maybe if you could clarify what you mean by "finish with `Infinity`".